# Merge [septic] and [septic-tanks]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

We currently have [septic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/septic) (77 Qs) and [septic-tanks](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/septic-tanks) (30 Qs)

Septic has this excerpt

> Questions related to septic systems

There's no real distinguishable difference here. The tags should be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion. I've put in the requested synonym, but haven't merged it yet to give the community time to discuss it. For now, any new questions will only be tagged with [septic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/septic).